# How to keep a mesh in the same location relative to its parent mesh?

Tags: mesh, particles

I am currently doing the donut tutorial and I'm trying to model M&M's for the particle lesson. The M&M's are modeled using a cylinder and a text that is converted into a mesh, with the text (the "m") awkwardly placed in the center of the cylinder:

[image: Particles]

However, when grouped together and used as particles it results in:
[image: Result]

How do I make it so that the text mesh is in the same location relative to the cylinder mesh; I don't want to join them because they result in the connecting vertices distorting the text a little. I think I have to use an object constraint but I'm not sure which one is appropriate for this example.

Answer (score 0):

The letters and the "buttons" are two separate object. In order to get them move together, they should be one object. One "m" should be joined with one "button".

First, select every "m" individually, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select "Rotation and Scale". Repeat this for every "m" and every "button".

Select the "m", then shift-select the "button", then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them. Repeat this for all six pairs.